# Problem with textmate minor mode

Tags: emacs

I try to load the textmate.el textmate minor mode in emacs.

I start trying to use the functionality and I see This buffer cannot use `imenu-default-create-index-function'. I can't find much help in google. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you type `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` before invoking that minor mode and post the stack trace?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I'm not sure how to start the minor mode from inside emacs. Normally, I edit my .emacs and uncomment the following: ;; (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")                                        
;; (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/textmate.el")                            
;; (require 'textmate)                                                          
;; (textmate-mode)

Comment: You can visit your .emacs buffer and type C-x C-e after the closing paren of an elisp expression to evaluate it, or type M-: and enter an elisp expression to evaluate. You should probably start reading the Emacs manual, it pays off quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message simply means that the mode in question does not support Imenu, so it cannot add or use an Imenu menu.  Consider filing and enhancement request with the author of the library.